# VisualForce Remoting not working with Separate AngularJS Controller File

Tags: angularjs, salesforce, visualforce

I'm facing an issue while working with Visualforce remoting and angularjs. Whenever I'm putting my controller code in separate js Static resource, my code doesn't work. Please help me in figuring out this.

My Visualforce page

```
    <apex:page controller="ApexRemoteActionPageController" docType="html-5.0">
<html>
<body>
 <div class="bootstrap" ng-app="ngApp" ng-controller="ContactCtrl" >

 <h1 align="center">Click The Button</h1>
 <button ng-click="getContacts()" class="btn btn-lg btn-default btn-block">Get Contacts</button> 

 <p>
 <ul>
 <li id="{{current.Id}}" ng-repeat="current in contacts" ng-class-even="'rowEven'">{{current.Name}}</li>
 </ul>
 </p>
</div>
<apex:stylesheet value="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/webjars/bootstrap-sf1/0.1.0-beta.6/css/bootstrap-namespaced.css"/>
 <apex:includeScript value="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.11/angular.min.js"/>
 <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.ContactCtrl}" />
</body>
</html>
</apex:page>
```

My Controller Static Resource

```
    <script>
var ngApp= angular.module("ngApp", []); 
 ngApp.controller("ContactCtrl", ["$scope", function($scope) 
                                 {
                                  $scope.contacts = [];
                                  $scope.getContacts = function() {
               ApexRemoteActionPageController.myContacts(function(result, event) {
               $scope.contacts = result;
               $scope.$apply();
});
}
}]);
</script>
```

My Apex Controller

```
global class ApexRemoteActionPageController {
@RemoteAction
global static List<Contact> myContacts() 
{
   return [select id, name, email from Contact Order By LastModifiedDate DESC LIMIT 30];
}
```

}

Whenever I put my controller logic in same Visual Force page it works, but when i move my controller script to separate js Static resource it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller static resource is a Javascript file and as such does not need `<script>` tags. Remove these and I believe your static resource will work as intended.

More detail: If you use `<script>` tags in your js file, you will end up with markup that nests the script tags and I don't think that will work for you. This is because `<includeScript>` renders to a script tag in the HTML markup.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found an answer. Yes part of the problem is using `<Script>` tag in static resource which needs to be removed, but the real problem was not placing namespace prefix before controller when placing a remoting call.

ApexRemoteActionPageController.myContacts(function(result, event)

needs to be

namespaceprefix. ApexRemoteActionPageController.myContacts(function(result, event)

Namespace prefix will not be set by default in Developer Edition, we have to navigate to ....Search bar on leftn hand side in dev account and search for create package ...go to packages and enable Managed package option ...which will give us option to set a namespace prefix for our entire account (classes.controllers...etc) and then come to javascript static resource and put your namespace before controller.methodname and thats it..